# I can't stop my Service (update my location) on my android app!

Tags: android, multithreading, service, geolocation

I've implemented a Service which update my current location and send it to my Server.
I only use with a ToggleButton: startService() to call the service and stopService() to stop it.
I've seen on the logCat that the service continue to run after calling stopService because when I restart the service, it update two time (three...or four..) my location.

My code:

Service: Geolocalisation.java

```
public class Geolocalisation extends Service{

private LocationManager locationManager;
//private String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
private String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

@Override
public void onCreate(){

    System.out.println("Service en cours !!");

    //Recuperation Location
    String locationContext = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(locationContext);
    if (locationManager != null && locationProvider != null) {

        majCoordonnes();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 10000, 0, new MajListener());

    }

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int StartId){
    System.out.println("Service commence !!");
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("geo", true);
    editor.commit();    
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    System.out.println("Service détruit !!");
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("geo", false);
    editor.commit();    

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){
    return null;
}


public void majCoordonnes() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Fournisseur :");
    stringBuilder.append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append(locationProvider);
    stringBuilder.append(" : ");
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

    if (location != null) {

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        String lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
        String lon = String.valueOf(longitude);

        stringBuilder.append(latitude);
        stringBuilder.append(", ");
        stringBuilder.append(longitude);

        //Send location to server
        new sendLocation().execute(lat, lon);

        System.out.println("Localisation:  "+ lat +" "+lon );


    } else {
        stringBuilder.append("Non déterminée");
    }
    //Log.d("MaPositionMaj", stringBuilder.toString());
}


/**
 * Ecouteur utilisé pour les mises à jour des coordonnées
 */
class MajListener implements android.location.LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        majCoordonnes();
        System.out.println("Update geo!");
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
    }
};
```

My Main.java which call and destroy the service by ToggleButton:

```
intentGeo = new Intent().setClass(this,Geolocalisation.class);

    Boolean boolLog = preferences.getBoolean("geo", false);

    final ToggleButton toggleAge = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleGeo);

    //Check ToggleButton if the service is already running
    if( boolLog != true){
        try{
            toggleAge.setChecked(false);

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Service Error");
        }       
    } else {
        toggleAge.setChecked(true);
    }

    //Activer ou désactivé le service de géolocalisation
    toggleAge.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            if (toggleAge.isChecked()) {

                try{
                    startService(intentGeo);
                    System.out.println("Turn ON");
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Service Error");
                }

            } else {

                try{
                    stopService(intentGeo);
                    System.out.println("Turn OFF");
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Service Error");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for your help !

PS I use Sharedpreference to determinate if Service is running or not. But if the service crash, it will occures a problem. How can I check the state of my Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to start and stop the service yourself. You can bind your activity to the service and then use methods on your service to stop/start it.

To bind to a service, you need to use something like this from your activity, probably in onCreate:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setClass(this, YourService.class);
bindService(serviceIntent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

There are some other boilerplate things you will need to do, described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample). Once your activity is bound to the service, you can then stop and start it using methods on your service class via a concrete object reference.

Just be sure to unbind from the service when your activity is destroyed!

```
unbindService(connection);
```

Comment: I should try this way (more difficult that call two native functions). I thank I was be able to start and stop my service simply calling startService and stopService...

Answer (score 2):

In your onDestroy function from Geolocalisation.java you are not ending the Listener, you are simply changing the variable that your program checks to see if the service is running or not. You could add code here to stop the location listener from running any further.

locationManager.removeUpdates(locationProvider);

should do the trick.

Comment: "The method removeUpdates(LocationListener) in the type LocationManager is not applicable for the arguments (String)". If I destroy the service, the listener won't listen to anymore, no?

Comment: You're only removing the listener from the manager in this case, the service is still there. You can re-add the locationprovider in the onStart function.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the trick, I don't know how can I remove updates. Can you show me by posting code?

Comment: add "locationManager.removeUpdates(locationProvider);" to onDestroy.

add "locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 10000, 0, new MajListener());" to onStart.

Comment: In fact, removeUpdates waited: "locationManager.removeUpdates(new MajListener());". I tested and the problem is still here...I can't stop the service or listener like this.

Answer (score 0):

To stop updating the server maybe you should overwrite the `stopService` function with the stopping code?

```
@Override
public stopService(Intent service)
{
    super.stopService();
    // code to stop updating server
}
```

Comment: The onDestroy method in the service might be a more appropriate location.